# Call a webpage in background in PHP and use jQuery on it

Tags: php, jquery

I have an HTML page which has a text box and a button...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form name = "inputdata" method ="get" action ="prc.php">
            <input type="text" name="data">
            <button id ="checkbox" type="buttton" name="submit" value="submit">Submit!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code for prc.php is...

```
<?php
    $data=$_GET['data'];
    echo "<html><head></head><body><div id=\"maindata\"> ";
    echo $data;
    echo "</div></body></html>";
?>
```

I have a PHP file which gets the contents of the previous page...

```
<?php
    file_get_contents("index.html");
?>
```

However, I would like to add functionality to the above PHP script such that it gets the page contents in the background and uses some jQuery on it:

```
$('#inputdata').val('hello boss');
$('#checkButton').click();
```

This will enable me to fill out the text box in the background and submit the button. Then I need to get the result from prc.php using jQuery...

```
$('#maindata').html();
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: That page can't be "rendered". You need a tool like Selenium to support rendering to an API. I think there are no viable solutions for JavaScript to do this. I hope someone can prove me wrong, for your sake :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to submit the form on the page. This should be possible by simply requesting the resource in the action field. In your example, requesting the url prc.php with a parameter called data which contains the data input data you wish to submit.

```
prc.php?data=mydata
```

Comment: Suppose the method is "post" then How do we achieve that ? Can you please let me know.

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials if you google it. This one looks good: http://fczaja.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/php-how-to-send-post-request-with.html